# Firebase - Cloud Firestore (collection)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I accidentally deleted the wrong collection from my project on cloud firestore. Is it be possible to restore it?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you are taking regular backups of your collections. Otherwise, no, it's not recoverable.